# "NameError - uninitialized constant" error when creating new association in has_many object. Plural issue?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm getting error: `NameError - uninitialized constant List::Listfavourite:`

This is referencing: `list.listfavourites.create(...)` from my controller. The `List` exits. Its association seems to be broken.

In other errors I've worked around, it sometimes looked for 'list_favourite', so I'm not sure where I've messed up with naming? I've checked other answers here and plural can be an issue.

When `db:migrate` was ran, a table called - `listfavourites` was made in my Postgres db.

**Schema:**

```rb
create_table "listfavourites", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "list_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "word_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.index ["list_id"], name: "index_listfavourites_on_list_id"
end

create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "word_id"
  t.string "text"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

**List:**

```rb
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listfavourites, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**ListFavourite:**

```rb
class ListFavourite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end
```

**Controller**

```rb
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  post '/list/:list_id/:word_id' do
    list_id = params["list_id"]
    word_id = params["word_id"]
    list = List.find_by(id: list_id, user_id: @user_id) # the list exists
    list.listfavourites.create(list_id: list_id, user_id: @user_id, word_id: word_id)
    list.to_json
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the directory and name of your files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a moment to read the documentation on [ActiveRecord Naming Conventions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.1/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions):

> The Rails pluralization mechanisms are very powerful, being capable of pluralizing (and singularizing) both regular and irregular words. When using class names composed of two or more words, the model class name should follow the Ruby conventions, using the CamelCase form, while the table name must use the snake_case form. Examples:
>
> - Model Class - Singular with the first letter of each word capitalized (e.g., `BookClub`).
> - Database Table - Plural with underscores separating words (e.g., `book_clubs`).

In your case, the table name `listfavourites` should be `list_favourites` because your class name is `ListFavourites`. Likewise your `has_many` call should be to `has_many :list_favourites`.

The cheat-sheet version of how to remember this is: *object names that contain multiple words **require** a separator of some kind between them, whether it's capitalization in `CamelCase` or underscores in `snake_case`*.

You should make a new migration that renames the table to `list_favourites` (and renames the index to `index_list_favourites_on_list_id`) and then update your code to ensure all references to `listfavourites` and `Listfavourite` have been corrected.

Do not try to go the other direction and rename everything to be `Listfavourite` and `listfavourites` -- Rails follows [convention over configuration](https://rubyonrails.org/doctrine#convention-over-configuration) and the convention is as I've described above.

Comment: I can't believe I skipped the basics when there's such a crazy rule. You were spot on! I changed my schema so the table name has the underscore and it works perfectly. Thank you taking the time to explain why this happens, makes sense.